# SQL : How to avoid multiple function call in a single query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query that accept the scalar-valued function 2 times, at one place in the field within the select list and second in the join condition. My question is that how to avoid that function call within single query?
Thanks.

```
SELECT   i.Id, i.Name, . . . . . dbo.IsItemCApproved(C.Id) AS [Status], . . 
FROM @Item i 
JOIN Card C ON C.ItemId = i.Id 
AND C.Deadline IS NOT NULL 
AND dbo.IsItemCApproved(C.Id) = 'False' 
AND C.IsDeleted = 0
```

Comment: Q: Example SQL please?  Q: What makes you think calling a function two times in the same query is necessarily a Bad Thing?  If that's what the statement needs, and it results in one and only one call to the server, then it's the optimal thing to do!

Comment: Low quality, please provide an example

Comment: SELECT 
i.Id,
i.Name,
.
.                            
.
. 
.
dbo.IsItemCApproved(C.Id) AS [Status],
.
.
FROM @Item i 
JOIN Card C ON C.ItemId = i.Id AND C.Deadline IS NOT NULL AND dbo.IsItemCApproved(C.Id) = 'False' AND C.IsDeleted = 0

Comment: You can *edit* your question. And *format* code in questions (using `{}`). Asif has already suggested an edit, you should just need to approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from
(
SELECT   i.Id, i.Name, . . . . . dbo.IsItemCApproved(C.Id) AS [Status], . . 
FROM @Item i 
JOIN Card C ON C.ItemId = i.Id 
AND C.Deadline IS NOT NULL 
AND C.IsDeleted = 0
)A
WHERE [Status] = 'False'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a CTE

```
with cte 
as 
(
    select
        id,
        calculated = myFunction(field1, field2)
    from
        table1
)
select
    id,
    field1,
    field2,
    calculated
from
    table1
inner join
    cte on cte.id = table1.id
where 
    cte.calculated = @someCondition
```

Or Sub querying

```
select
    id,
    field1,
    field2,
    calculated
from
(
    select 
        field1,
        field2,
        calculated = myFunction(field1, field2)
    from
        table1
) t
where
    calculated = @someCondition
```